# Opening an uploaded Document - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload a `.js` file.

My model (Bypassing validation just for Testing Purposes):

```
# Script Asset
has_attached_file :asset
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :asset
```

The upload itself works as it should, but how to open the uploaded file so i can display it in the View?

I tried and searched a lot, but i can't find a working solution. Just passing `<%= @test.asset %>` brings back the path of the Document.

Do i have to write a method for passing the Document to a `text` ?

Comment: unless i missed your question

<%= javascript_include_tag @test.asset %>

Comment: No No, you missed it :) Think of it like a Text file uploaded by a user.. I want to show the content of that Text File.

Comment: ah..see if this helps 
Paperclip.io_adapters.for(@test.asset).read
doesn't require writing to (and removing from) the local file system.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555468/how-do-you-access-the-content-of-a-text-file-uploaded-with-paperclip-ruby-on-r

Comment: Oh, i literally searched 100 SO Questions and didn't found that! You mind answering so i can upvote ?

Comment: In that case..Did the needful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Paperclip.io_adapters.for(@test.asset).read
```

Doesn't require writing to (and removing from) the local file system.