# How to save uploaded file in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, zoho

Hi I have integrated Zoho sheet in Rails 2 app , where I can open new Zoho Sheet from local , but when i click on save at zoho editor , it will send me the file to my server,
this is my production log

```
 Processing ZohoController#index to #<File:0x6a49f88> (for *.*.*.*      at 2015-10-08 11:24:08) [POST]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"zoho", "filename"=>#      <File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151008-2490-oxplae-0>, "content"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151008-2490-3r5nf3-0>, "eventsource"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151008-2490-yj8j8h-0>, "format"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151008-2490-1nfald4-0>, "id"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151008-2490-yeqxb8-0>, "action"=>"index"}
 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

I couldn't fetch the file , can anyone please help me out how can access file, even though i inspected each params , but i couldn't achieve
Any help is valuable

Comment: Try https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: How can i read File through PaperClip

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555468/how-do-you-access-the-content-of-a-text-file-uploaded-with-paperclip-ruby-on-r

Comment: Processing ZohoController#index to #<File:0x6a49f88>  what this means, hw to i get that file  #<File:0x6a49f88>

Comment: You can access the file with file's path with `File.path`. Read the documentation of the File object : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html

Answer (score 1):

The server log shows "Invalid Authenticity Token" message.  This means that the token saved by rails server in a previous requests cookie did not match the token sent with your POST request.

If this is the first interaction for this service/server and no previous token is available, you an skip this validation for this particular action (i.e index action)

```
class FooController < ApplicationController


 protect_from_forgery except: :index
```

For further understanding this topic please see [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token)